# Regex for specific word

Tags: java, regex

I was trying to write a regular expression for "[beginning word][specific word][ending word]" and making it case insensitive. But for some reason it doesn't seem to work.

I'm doing it in java, hence the extra "\".

For example, if I wanted to match the word "crazy" my regex would be:

```
/\\bcrazy\\b/i
```

My java code in which I call the regular expression where it doesn't match anything is:

```
textToMakeHarder = textToMakeHarder.replaceAll("/\\bcrazy\\b/i", "super crazy");
```

Comment: Not sure, but maybe `end of line` does not match `end of word`. Have you tried "super crazy me"?

Comment: Give us some sample text on which you wanna run this.

Comment: if textToMakeHarder = "Dragons dance crazy." it's supposed to replace "crazy" with "super crazy." I've tried it on dance and crazy with a couple different things to replace it with, but it's just not replacing them at all. replaceAll accepts (Regex patternToMatch, String toReplaceThePatternWhenMatched)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
  String textToMakeHarder = "I am a crazy person and he is also a crazy person. Are you crazycrazy too?";
  Pattern re = Pattern.compile("\\bcrazy\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
  Matcher m = re.matcher(textToMakeHarder);
  textToMakeHarder = m.replaceAll("super crazy");
```

Result:

> I am a super crazy person and he is also a super crazy person. Are you
>   crazycrazy too?

Comment: Ahhh, this is probably what I need! Let me try this and see if it works.

Comment: Yep. It's interesting that the /i stuff doesn't work. I got it fully working with this though. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the `/` and `/i`, and use a `Pattern` to get case insensitivity:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\bcrazy\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher match = pattern.matcher(textToMakeHarder);

textToMakeHarder = match.replaceAll("super crazy");
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Pattern pat = Pattern("\\bcrazy\\b",Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
Matcher mat = pat.matcher("Your_Input");

while(mat.find()){

   mat.replaceAll("super crazy");

}
```

Comment: I do need it to check that it has the beginning and ending of a word. For example, in the sentence "Are you sure you care?" I don't want the "are" part of "care" replaced by synonyms of "are." When I make "crazy" as a pattern can I still add the regular expression values for /\\bcrazy\\b/i around it to ensure it's not part of another word, and is case insensitive?

Comment: this will also match `acrazya`, which should not be matched

Comment: @CorayThan and Ankur Sorry dear, i just missed out the \\b , i am editing it now.

Comment: Keep in mind you need a look-ahead `(?=\\b+)` and a look-behind `(?<=\\b+)` for word boundaries. --- That code, as is, would find any matches to the pattern, including when they are not words themselves but are contained within the input as something else. --- For example: The phrase `"Invalid input makes this program inoperable."` has quite a potential for errors...A search for the word `"valid"` gives a match within "in**valid**"...If the search is for `"in"`, hell breaks loose: "**in**valid **in**put makes this program **in**operable".

Answer (score 1):

You'd want to try this simpler version:

```
String textToMakeHarder = "foo bar is CraZY tonight".replaceAll("(?i)\\bcrazy\\b", "super crazy");
```

Output is:

```
foo bar is super crazy tonight
```

Using the short modifier (?i) for case-insensitive search.

[Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) to offficial Java 7 docs for Patterns